# create_autonomy keyboard control

Tags: ros, create-autonomy, create2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
Can create_autonomy can support keyboard input? I'd like to control my create2 using simple keyboard commands like forward, backward, rotate clockwise and rotate counterclockwise.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262883/create_autonomy-keyboard-control/) by [fj138696](https://answers.ros.org/users/30352/fj138696/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2017-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try existing packages like

1. key_teleop: http://wiki.ros.org/key_teleop
2. teleop_twist_keyboard: http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_keyboard

---

Originally posted by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) with karma: 544 on 2017-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fj138696](https://answers.ros.org/users/30352/fj138696/) on 2017-05-31**:
Hi DavidN!
I tried both package and can simply drive my create2. Thanks alot!